# Changing layout background depending on theme

Tags: android, layout

I've got the following element:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/giftsLayout">
```

And my *style.xml* file is

```
<style name="ChristmasTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/christmas_background</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#03426A</item>
</style>
<style name="BirthdayTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/birthday_background</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#03426A</item>
</style>
```

I need in dependence of ChristmasTheme or BirthdayTheme application themes set my background to my LinearLayout or better to my LinearLayout with id giftsLayout. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add this to/create `attr.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <attr name="windowBackground" format="reference" />
</resources>
```

Then in your View:

```
android:background="?attr/windowBackground"
```

Then Android takes care of when to switch backgrounds, assuming you change themes correctly; of course.

Comment: @IEVGEN, not a problem. If you have more drawables that are theme dependant you can switch them using the same method. Useful for switching from `Dark` drawables to `Light` ones, or vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, do you need a way to change theme/background?
You have to do that at runtime, in onCreate method.

You can use [setTheme()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#setTheme%28int%29) method defining a condition (a date for example) or let the user choose when to switch..